# In Call of Duty: Black Ops What gun is recommended for a person with horrible aim?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, xbox-360

Also what are the best attachments for that gun?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest an SMG, probably AK47u with a grip and silencer.

The gun has enough ammo per clip so that you can spray if you like.

Grip will reduce the amount of recoil and give you a chance at mid-range.

The silencer will not reveal your position while you shoot, so you have a little more time lining up the shots.

You can setup the perks as Lightweight, Steady Aim and Second Chance to give you a further edge.

Lightweight to help you dodge the enemy, ( faster strafing ). Steady aim for well steady aim when shooting from the hip and second chance ( pro if possible ) for revenge with a pistol.

Comment: He means to say he has very rough aim, any gun needing ADS to shoot something will be ineffective. Grip takes the shakiness away, but as long as you can't *aim* at your target, it won't do anything good.

Comment: i don't see why it would matter. If he is bad at ADS aiming now, doesn't mean he doesn't want to do it or can't do it at all. Plus the setup I suggest would work at close range spraying anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered multiple times but here's my two cents....

At one point my game was getting so terrible due to horrible aim that I simply gave up and instead of wanting to rank up, aimed towards actually going out an having some fun in the game.

Enter the M60!

Wanting to make some noise and be a general nuisance since I was sucking anyway, I created a heavily armed LMG class with an M60 Extended Mag + Grip (Warlord Perk), Frag grenade + Willy Pete, C4 and a RPG as a secondary.

My perks were Flak Jacket, Warlord and Marathon.

You will not believe how many killscores I was racking up.

Here's the reason why: The M60, though lacking in accuracy and fire rate, more than makes 
up in the damage department. To top that, any player you hit has so much throwback from the bullet impacts that it usually gives you a chance to hit him again (this makes up for the low fire rate).

I know this sounds crazy but novice players should really try out the M60. No matter how inaccurate a gun is, the first bullet is usually on target and the high damage makes sure that it leaves a mark! (I've taken out snipers using one tap bursts of the M60).

And lastly, this may just be me but it's the most satisfying gun to shoot with in terms of force feedback and sound :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to stick to something that covers a large area like a shotgun  OR you can use an assult rifle with either a flame thrower attachment or grenade launcher attachment.  With either of those attachments you will wound or kill anyone within a decent sized area.

Comment: I agree with the shotgun or a gun with a flame thrower or grenade launcher attachment. Secondary launchers (M72 LAW, RPG-7, China Lake) are fine, too.

Comment: A grenade launcher is going to require perfect aim at close quarters since the explosive won't go off (you need a direct hit with the canister) and a long distances it can be very hard to aim (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

I think the AK47u w/ grip is perfect for someone with better aim, but it lacks range. I'd suggest the M-16, the FAMAS, or the Commando for all-around game play. You can put a red dot sight on any one. Don't forget to put the sensitivity on the lowest setting and to use steady aim.

Comment: yeah.. this is a very good point, play around with the sensitivity settings and see what works for you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you go with Dual Wield SMGs. Try to stay away from big, empty spaces and if anything moves on your screen, start shooting. As soon as you see the cross-hairs turn into an X you're hitting them, so just try to keep that X up.

With the dual wield you'll lose accuracy, but when you do get the jump on someone and connect it's a very quick death for them. That also means it's less likely that they'll have a chance to move, causing you to have to adjust your aim.